# c# - How to remove matching items from a list using Linq or otherwise

Tags: c#

I'm trying to remove matching items from a list, which seems like a pretty simple task, but as luck would have it, I can't figure it out.

Example list:

```
List<int> points1 = new List<int>
{
    1, 2, 3, 3
};
```

I'm trying to get `uniquePoints1` to be `1,2`

I know there is [.Distinct()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=net-5.0) but that would return `1,2,3` which is not what I want.

I've also tried the following along with `.Distinct()` but I get a red line saying `Comparison made to the same variable, did you mean to compare to something else?`

```
List<int> uniquePoints1 = points1.Where(x => x == x);
List<int> uniquePoints1 = points1.RemoveAll(x => x == x);
```

Any help or direction is appreciated.

Comment: @RufusL how is that different from `.Distinct()`?

Comment: @BabakNaffas It returns only the items that have a count of `1`. Distinct returns all unique items, regardless of how many there are.

Comment: https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/issues/125#issuecomment-302395031 - similar to the `GroupBy` approaches suggested here, without the need to store all of the elements (i.e. likely less memory pressure).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `GroupBy` method to group the items, and then return only the numbers from groups that have a count of `1`:

```
List<int> uniquePoints = points
    .GroupBy(x => x)              // Group all the numbers
    .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)   // Filter on only groups that have one item
    .Select(g => g.Key)           // Return the group's key (which is the number)
    .ToList();

// uniquePoints = { 1, 2 }
```

Answer (score 3):

"Group by" to the rescue!

This is a LINQ variant -- see other answers for a non-LINQ version

```
var nonDuplicatedPoints = from p in points1
                          group p by p into g 
                          where g.Count() == 1
                          select g.Key;
```